# How can I write a range to a command, and then read the resulting output?

Tags: command-line, external-command, normal-mode

I have an SQL file that I have to work on from the command line.

```
-- Query 1
select 1;
-- Query 2
select *
from metadata;
```

I've marked line `4` as `a` (`4Gma`) and line `5` as `b` (`5Gmb`), then execute `:'a,'b w !mysql -u root db \| less` to view the contents. I've mapped this snippet to `F5` so that I can simply reset marks `a` and `b` and press `F5` to see the result. This works fine.

What I want to do now is insert the results of the query into the document, much like what `:r !cmd` provides. I know I can replace `%s` in `r !cmd`, but `%s` is replaced with the filename, and I only want to execute the SQL query in the current range.

Is this possible, and if so, how?

Answer (score 3):

There is a `:h range!` which I think will do the trick here.

```
:'a,'b!mysql -u root db
```

I tested it with `sed` on file with content:

```
line1
line2
line3
```

Vim commands:

```
1Gma
3Gmb
:'a,'b!sed -n '/1/p'
```

Result:

```
line1
```